# Get avatar of nitro users

Tags: discord.py

I am currently developing a bot for Discord using discord.py.

The bot is triggered using Slash Commands. One of the parameter of my slash command is a user object. I need the URL of the user's avatar. I can get that by using the property `avatar_url` of the user object. It works just fine with regular users.

The problem comes with Nitro users. They can choose to have a special avatar depending on the guild they are on. When they choose to, the property `avatar_url` gives the "default" avatar, not the one currently in use in the guild.

I tried to use the Member object instead, but `avatar_url` still points to the default avatar, and not the guild-specific avatar.

```py
# userobj is the user object given by the slash command
# context is the context object given by the slash command
member = context.guild.get_member(userobj.id)
if member:
    print(userobj.avatar_url)
    print(member.avatar_url) # They are the same
```

Do you know how I can get the URL of the guild-specific avatar of nitro users instead of the default avatar?

Comment: This feature was added on [October 15th](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409388345495-Server-Avatars) and discord.py was last updated on [June 12th](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/#history). Unfortunately, I think this feature might just not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMPORTANT: Only available in v2.0+**

You might be able to use `discord.Member.guild_avatar`.

> Returns an `Asset` for the guild avatar the member has. If unavailable, `None` is returned.

Note that this returns a `discord.Asset` object, so you'll need to access it's url using `discord.Member.guild_avatar.url`

```
member = context.guild.get_member(userobj.id)

if member:
    print(userobj.avatar_url) # User avatar
    print(member.avatar_url)  # Member avatar (same as user avatar)

    if member.guild_avatar:
        print(member.guild_avatar.url)
    else:
        print("No Guild Avatar")
```

Comment: You might also want to mention that you need v2.0+

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Added it!

Comment: v2.0 introduces a lot of changes. My code breaks with it, but I'll figure out what's wrong and test your solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Slagt If you don't want to use `v2.0`, you can always use the API by itself.

Answer (score 2):

For the [`latest`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) version of the discord.py, (which is v1.7.3 afaik) there is no way to do this but it exists in the [`master`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/) aka 2.0 unreleased version of the discord.py.

[Check this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=avatar#discord.User.display_avatar).

Comment: Thanks! My code breaks with v2.0, I need to figure out why before I can test.

Answer (score 1):

[TheNightHawk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16990573/thenighthawk)'s answer is the proper answer to my question. However, I ended up implementing a direct call to the API itself, as [TheNightHawk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16990573/thenighthawk) suggested, and I thought it would be nice to share this solution too.

```py
import json
import requests

guild_id   = ...
user_id    = ...
token      = ...
appurl     = ... # Can be anything
appversion = ... # Can be anything

url      = f"https://discord.com/api/guilds/{guild_id}/members/{user_id}"
res      = requests.get(url, headers = {
                 "Authorization": f"Bot {token}",
                 "User-Agent":    f"DiscordBot ({appurl}, {appversion})"})
data     = json.loads(res.content)

if data['avatar'] is None:
    avatar_ext = ("gif"
                  if data['user']['avatar'].startswith("a_")
                  else "png")
    avatar_url = ( "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/" +
                  f"{user_id}/{data['user']['avatar']}" +
                  f".{avatar_ext}?size=1024")
else:
    avatar_ext = ("gif"
                  if data['avatar'].startswith("a_")
                  else "png")

    avatar_url = ( "https://cdn.discordapp.com/guilds/" +
                  f"{guild_id}/users/{user_id}/avatars/" +
                  f"{data['avatar']}.{avatar_ext}?size=1024")
```